# Estructura de datos de entrada en un content-type: form-data Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, http-post

Me están pidiendo que envie mediante el metodo post unos datos. Os dejo el código primero:

```
addImage(image, params): Observable<any> {


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': this.token,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Content-Disposition': `form-data; filename=${image.name}`
  })
};
this.data = params;
this.data.file = image;
return this.http.post(this.url , this.data, httpOptions);
```

La petición así, no les vale, creo que lo que esperan recibir son los datos de un formulario (formulario que ni existe, ni va a existir). Hay alguna forma de simular como sería esa entrada. Es decir como simular la entrada que nos daría el formulario al lanzarse?.

Un saludo.

Comment: Params qué es? ¿un objeto cuyos atributos quieres mandar?

Comment: Si, correcto. Es un objeto, sin embargo si hago tal como está ahora y se lo mando en el body añadiendo la imagen al objeto, no les gusta.

Comment: Quieres enviar una imagen o un objeto? O los dos?

Comment: Se envian una serie de datos, yo ahora mismo los estoy enviado como un objeto, uno de los atributos del objeto es la imagen en binario, pero creo que eso es lo de menos. El problema es que quieren que les llegue la información como si viniera de un formulario.

Comment: Tienes que crear un FormData y enviarlo con los datos requeridos. El parametro image es de la clase File?

Comment: Si es de tipo file. Que lo hago creando un formData y usado la fución .append?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un FormData y añadir la imagen así:

```
const fd= new FormData();
fd.append('nombre',image, image.name); //el nombre del fichero es opcional
```

y añadir el resto de valores del formulario de manera similar:

```
fd.append('atributo',data.atributo);
...
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': this.token,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  });
};
this.http.post(url,fd,options);
```

Comment: Pues no le está teminando de gustar. En el Request Payload se ve así:

------WebKitFormBoundaryOSdoJZUifGlHXhY2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="usuario"

Findelias

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="producto"

Ventana

Comment: @Findelias Así es como functiona. En el server eso se traduce en `key='producto'` y `value=[..fichero]`

Comment: vale, entoces hablaré con la gente del back. Porque por POSTMAN si me está funcionando @devconcept no se si eso es normal..

Comment: @Findelias Postan entiende el `multipart/form-data` así que por detrás te está haciendo exactamente lo mismo que el navegador. En el fondo todo tiene que seguir el spec del HTTP

Comment: Pues las respuestas no están siendo la misma, así que algo estoy haciendo mal xD

Comment: @Findelias Edita e incluye en tu pregunta el status code que te devuelve el servidor y la respuesta. Con la información que hay es imposible saber que es lo que anda mal.

Comment: No sé si ayudará, ya que realmente la info llega porque devuelve un 201, pero tendría que montar una url en base a los parametros que le envio donde almacenar la imagen, sin embargo no monta dicha URL, en postman si.

Comment: La pongo como correcta, porque ya tiene toda la pinta que el problema cae del servicio que nos han publicado más que de la parte frontal.

Mucha gracias!